# Append to a 3D array written to file

Tags: arrays, r, save

I'm running a long MCMC chain for Bayesian analysis. Every 1000 iterations, I would like to write my intermediate results, which are 3D arrays, to disk in order to free up memory.

Two potential solutions that don't work for me yet:

1. With a matrix, I can easily `write.table(my_matrix, "filename", append = TRUE)`. However, writing a 3D array this way flatten it into 2D. I *could* reshape the 2D matrix back into 3D. However, this requires writing down the original dimension somewhere other than the file itself, which does not facilitate reproducibility.
2. I can `saveRDS(my_array, "filename")`. However, I can't continuously append new MCMC samples to this file.

Comment: Does this discussion help? https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/101282.html

Comment: `tar`ing the individual `.Rdata` file together is a potential solution. Reading the file requires untar-ing and concatenating the array. If there isn't a cleaner solution I may go with this.